# PHP - How to append array with some conditions

Tags: php, arrays

```
$list = array(
               [0]=> array(
                            [name]=>'James' 
                            [group]=>''
                          )
               [1]=> array(
                            [name]=>'Bobby' 
                            [group]=>''
                          )
             )
```

I am looking to update the item 'group' where the name is 'Bobby'. I am looking for a solution with the two following formats. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

```
array_push($list, ???)
```

and

```
$list[] ??? = someting
```

Comment: Why two formats, unless this is homework, in which case, tag it as such, and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: You won't be able to "update" a existing array by pushing. I think you either need to foreach through the array until you find the one you want or if you know, access it directly $list[1]['group'] = 'new group';

Comment: Can't you just look over your array, check for the `name` field in every index and update the `group` accordingly?

Comment: Hello Yaniro. This could be a solution, but I have no idea how to achieve that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way updating your array with one of the given syntax.

The only similar thing I can come on is looping over the array using array_walk ... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Example:

```
array_walk($list, function($val, $key) use(&$list){
    if ($val['name'] == 'Bobby') {
        // If you'd use $val['group'] here you'd just editing a copy :)
        $list[$key]['group'] = "someting";
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Example is using anonymous functions which is only possible since PHP 5.3. Documentation offers also ways working with older PHP-versions.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you:

```
$listSize = count($list);

for( $i = 0; $i < $listSize; ++$i ) {
    if( $list[$i]['name'] == 'Bobby' ) {
        $list[$i]['group'] = 'Hai';
    }
}
```

`array_push()` doesn't really relate to updating a value, it only adds another value to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a solution that will fit both formats. The implicit array push `$var[]` is a syntactic construct, and you cannot invent new ones - certainly not in PHP, and not most (all?) other languages either.

Aside from that, what you are doing is *not* pushing an item on to the array. For one thing, pushing items implies an indexed array (yours is associative), and for another pushing implies adding a key to the array (the key you want to update already exists).

You can write a function to do it, something like this:

```
function array_update(&$array, $newData, $where = array(), $strict = FALSE) {
  // Check input vars are arrays
  if (!is_array($array) || !is_array($newData) || !is_array($where)) return FALSE;
  $updated = 0;
  foreach ($array as &$item) { // Loop main array
    foreach ($where as $key => $val) { // Loop condition array and compare with current item
      if (!isset($item[$key]) || (!$strict && $item[$key] != $val) || ($strict && $item[$key] !== $val)) {
        continue 2; // if item is not a match, skip to the next one
      }
    }
    // If we get this far, item should be updated
    $item = array_merge($item, $newData);
    $updated++;
  }
  return $updated;
}

// Usage
$newData = array(
  'group' => '???'
);
$where = array(
  'name' => 'Bobby'
);

array_update($list, $newData, $where);

// Input $array and $newData array are required, $where array can be omitted to
// update all items in $array. Supply TRUE to the forth argument to force strict
// typed comparisons when looking for item(s) to update. Multiple keys can be
// supplied in $where to match more than one condition.

// Returns the number of items in the input array that were modified, or FALSE on error.
```